# Unable to highlight/choose select option on mobile Safari (iPhone & iPad) but works fine on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, mobile, safari

Dynamically choosing a select menu option fails on mobile Safari and Chrome (both iPhone & iPad), though it works on desktop Chrome.

Reproduce:

1) Visit http://www.panabee.com/show-hn?time=7-days on your mobile device. On desktop browsers, the `Last 7 days of Show HN` option is chosen. On mobile, the `Last 24 hours of Show HN option` is incorrectly selected.

Code:

```
<select class='time_menu'>
    <option value='24-hours'>Last 24 hours</option>
    <option value='7-days'>Last 7 days</option>
    <option value='30-days'>Last 30 days</option>
</select>

$( document ).ready( function() {
            ... (other stuff)

    // Bind time menu
    var time_menu = $( '.content_body .time_menu' );
            ... (other stuff)

    // Display corresponding option in time menu
    var time = get_parameter( 'time' );
    var menu_option = time_menu.find( 'option[value="' + time + '"]' );
    if ( menu_option.length == 0 ) {
        menu_option = time_menu.find( 'option[value="24-hours"]' );
    }
    menu_option.attr( 'selected', true );
});
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate this using Safari OR Chrome on Android 4.4

Comment: Sorry should state more explicitly this is iOS tested only. Thanks for checking Android.

Comment: Ah. My apologies, I own no iOS devices. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks! Incidentally, any odd formatting errors on Android?

Comment: Nope, looks great. Well done.

Comment: Thanks, but it's just a temporary thing until they offer a dedicated link for SH posts. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when working with dropdowns. I don't have any iOS devices to test with but maybe my solution will work for you. Originally I tried setting which option was selected by adding the selected attribute to the HTML like you are doing but it wouldn't take it. I ended up having to change which option was selected through the DOM properties. (Using selectedIndex).

For example

```
var time_menu = document.querySelector('.time_menu'),
time = get_parameter('time'),
index = 0;

if(time == '7-days'){
    index = 1;
}else if(time == '30-days'){
    index = 2;
}

time_menu.selectedIndex = index;
```